# Problem with volley POST and response null from the server (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, post, request, android-volley

I got a problem with my Volley POST in kotlin :

When I use this following code, my application go on "Response.Listener", but the array is null, so when I try to display the information I've just send, I can only get "null".

May you guys help me? :)

There is the kotlin code :

```
 private fun sendHtmlRequest(view: View){

        val emailreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_email)
        val pwdreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_password)
        val email = emailreq.text.toString()
        val pwd = pwdreq.text.toString()
        val jsonobj = JSONObject()
        var url = "https://www.dorian-roulet.com/testStage-master/mobileApp/testpostone.php"

        jsonobj.put("mail", email)
        jsonobj.put("pwd", pwd)


        val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche $response $jsonobj")
                    println("Yessai")
                }, Response.ErrorListener{
                view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche pas mec $jsonobj")
                println("Erreur")
            }
            )

        que.add(req)
    }
```

Now, there is the PHP code :

```
<?php
$reponse = array("mail" => $_POST["mail"], "pwd" => $_POST["pwd"]);
echo json_encode($reponse);
?>
```

I tried to use a GET to recieve this data from a GET array, but the problem still being...
And when I go on my server's logs, I cans ee that I have a POST request from my application (even if I can't see what's in the request).

I use this code to do a Login task, but atm, I just want to send a post request from my application.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Your PHP code is **NOT** fine.
To get JSON data you should not use $_POST (even if it was send with post). Use this instead:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$reponse = array("mail" => $data["mail"], "pwd" => $data["pwd"]);
echo json_encode($reponse);
?>
```

Here is a code that work for volley (it's not too different than what you have :-) ):

```
val jsonObjectRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url, **jsonobj**, Response.Listener { response: JSONObject ->
        try {
            val email = response.getString("email")
            val password = response.getString("password")
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            // catch/handle JSON error
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // catch/handle other error
        }
    }, Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError ->
        //Error Listener code
    }) {
        override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        
        // you can override more functions here if needed (getHeader, etc.)
    }
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

For your case it would likely give:

```
    private fun sendHtmlRequest(view: View){

    val emailreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_email)
    val pwdreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_password)
    val email = emailreq.text.toString()
    val pwd = pwdreq.text.toString()
    val jsonobj = JSONObject()
    var url = "https://www.dorian-roulet.com/testStage-master/mobileApp/testpostone.php"

    jsonobj.put("mail", email)
    jsonobj.put("pwd", pwd)


    val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj,
        Response.Listener { response: JSONObject ->
            val mailBack = response.getString("mail")
            val pwdBack = response.getString("pwd")
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche $response $mailBack - $pwdBack")
            println("Yessai")
        }, Response.ErrorListener{
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche pas mec $jsonobj")
            println("Erreur")
        }
    )

    que.add(req)
}
```

Comment: Hi,
First, thanks for your answere, but the problem still the same : the response is null.
On the debugger, I see : "response={JSONObject@16756}"{"mail":null,"pwd":null}".
Do you know why? ^^'
Is it because it's an asynchronous function and I try to use it on the Fragment I display?

Comment: Your code does not recover the values. you need to use "response.getString("mail")". Update the code you have on your question so I can point out the issue if you want!

Comment: I've just put an answere on my question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the code I have after you send me what code I have to put inside :
*(Still returns null values)*

```
        private fun sendHtmlRequest(view: View){

    val emailreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_email)
    val pwdreq = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_password)
    val email = emailreq.text.toString()
    val pwd = pwdreq.text.toString()
    val jsonobj = JSONObject()
    var url = "https://www.dorian-roulet.com/testStage-master/mobileApp/testpostone.php"

    jsonobj.put("mail", email)
    jsonobj.put("pwd", pwd)


    val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj,
        Response.Listener { response: JSONObject ->
            val emails = response.getString("mail")
            val passwords = response.getString("pwd")
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche $emails $passwords $response $jsonobj")
    }, Response.ErrorListener {
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_login)?.text = ("Ca marche pas mec $jsonobj")
        println("Erreur")
    }) /*{
        override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        // you can override more functions here if needed (getHeader, etc.)
    }*/
    que.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

Comment: Reading after a fresh nights helps :-) the issue you have is with the PHP! $_POST is not what you should use to get the JSON variables :-), check my updated answer!